# Why does this result in a syntax error? Is it something to do with the Boolean value?

Tags: python

```
def less0(x):
    print(bool(x <= 0)
less0(10)
```

```
File "filename.py", line 75
    less0(10)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see a syntax error in the line of code in the error message, check the lines above it.

You're missing a closing parenthesis in the call to `print` on line 2. Fixed:

```
def less0(x):
    print(bool(x <= 0))
```

Although `x <= 0` already returns a `bool`, and printing in a function is generally bad practice. It would be better to write it like this:

```
def less0(x):
    return x <= 0
print(less0(10))
```